# How data is transferred over network?

Tags: networking

I have learned OSI model and my understanding is this.We browse a website and request a webpage.So HTTP here goes to application layer.Encryption here can be referred to presentation layer.Now session layer where session started.Coming down it comes transport layer where error checking and segmentation is done.After that network layer where routing is decided and broken down into packets.Now in data link layer framing is done and finally in physical layer frames are converted into bits i.e. 0 and 1 and transferred over wire or as signal.
So my question is this.Does data is transferred as bits or packets?? Uptil now i have read that data is transferred as packet?? but how it is possible??I mean packets are also broken down and last layer is physical so it may be transferred as bits?? What is correct answer for this?? And my other ques is this.We know that router is network layer device.what does this means?? Does it means that data after coming to network layer skips data link and physical layer and directly goes to router as router only routes packets not bits which is received from physical?? I apologize if i have written something wrong.I am newbie in networking.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to answer this in a simplified manner.

I think you're missing the point on the purpose of layers. As far as the physical layers go, data is transferred as bits over the wire.

But as soon as those bits are received "from the wire" on the **physical layer**, they are sent upwards to the **data layer** and assembled into groups of bits which can be interpreted as frames in the same data layer.

Data layer assembles those frames together and makes them meaningful to the **network link layer** to where it passes them further. Now in the network link layer that same data can be interpreted as ***packets***.

Basically, it is the same data being transferred, but whether you talk about bits or packets, **depends on what layer of the networking stack you are referring to**. That is actually the whole point of the layered architecture. Different layers interpret the same data from a different point of abstraction. 
Essentially it is easier to refer to packets instead of bits when you talk about network communication, because packets have IP addresses and people/programmers use those addresses to perform routing and send packets to desired destinations. That's why most of the time people talk about packets, not bits.

And for your other question, **on routers being network layer devices**, it means that they include all the layers up to network layer. So when the packets are received they go through physical, data and network layer. Beacuse the IP addresses are visible on network layer, they can perform routing on that layer and then they forward the packet to some destination, after which the packet goes again from the network layer down through data and physical layer again "through the wire". So, basically, on routers, higher layers than network layer is not required (basically :-) ).